# how to check if official Debian/Ubuntu apt repositories are enabled in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: 16.04, apt

I was following iRedmail documentation and came across this line

iRedMail needs official Debian/Ubuntu apt repositories, please enable them in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

How do I go about checking if this is true?

I am using 16.04 headless server edition

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu, you have official repositories. You can check with cat /etc/apt/sources.list. See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: The following may be helpful - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  however which repositories you wish to use will mean the right repositories for you may differ for another person (eg. support for 'universe' differs to 'main' so release data of your version & actual date has impact, let alone your security choices...)

Comment: Thanks all. I am using headless server edition. So these GUI screenshots in the link not applicable.

Comment: Re-read oldfred's comment above. He told you the headless way to check....

Comment: Thanks all. I guess this means I have enabled the official repositories

Answer (score 1):

Tested with 16.04 Ubuntu headless

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

You should see something like

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Usually the repositories with the description `main` are the official supported repositories.